# Query to delete all rows which are not referenced in any other tables

Tags: mysql, cron

Let's say i have a table called **images**. **Images** table is referenced in many other tables (**movies**, **books**, **tv_series**) through a foreign key.

My question is if it is possible to write a query which will delete all orphaned rows without specifying exact tables (eg `JOIN movies ON ...`). This is important because if new table which references **images** will be introduced it will make the query outdated. If the query will be executed without changes it could delete images which are used in new table.

Comment: I got lost reading the Question.  Could you improve on the wording?

Comment: Do you mean some sort of event code that determines all the tables which reference images and after that, then deletes the images which are orphaned?

Comment: @RickJames. I can write a query using joins, but I need to specify which tables to join. I am asking for a query which auto join the required tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can write a single query, but you can write a query to get the list of tables that refer to the `images` table, and then you can do a second task which deletes the rows from `images` which are not referred to in any of the tables in the list.

**List of tables that refer to the images table:**

```
SELECT rf.TABLE_NAME, 
kcu.COLUMN_NAME, 
kcu.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME 
FROM information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS rf 
  INNER JOIN information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE kcu ON 
    kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = rf.CONSTRAINT_NAME AND
    kcu.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA=rf.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA 
WHERE rf.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'images' AND 
  rf.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = 'your_database';
```

**Delete all rows in images not referred to by those tables:**

For this part, perhaps it's better to do a loop and look at one and one row in `images`. Assume '$row_i_val' is the PK column value of the current row you're looking at:

```
SELECT sum(q.c) FROM 
(
  SELECT count(*) as c FROM $table1 WHERE $table1_col = $row_i_val
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT count(*) as c FROM $table2 WHERE $table2_col = $row_i_val
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT count(*) as c FROM $table3 WHERE $table3_col = $row_i_val
  UNION ALL ...
) q
```

If this sum is 0, then you can delete it:

```
DELETE FROM images WHERE pk_col = $row_i_val;
```

Comment: For deleting, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384127/delete-sql-rows-where-ids-do-not-have-a-match-from-another-table#3384143), with multiple `LEFT JOINS` and `IS NULL` criteria.

Comment: The outer needs to be `SELECT SUM(...) FROM...`